# Using expanding strings as Powershell function parameters

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation, variable-expansion

I'm trying to write a function that will print a user-supplied greeting addressed to a user-supplied name. I want to use expanding strings the way I can in this code block:

```
$Name = "World"  
$Greeting = "Hello, $Name!"
$Greeting
```

Which successfully prints `Hello, World!`. However, when I try to pass these strings as parameters to a function like so,

```
function HelloWorld
{  
    Param ($Greeting, $Name)
    $Greeting
}
HelloWorld("Hello, $Name!", "World")
```

I get the output

```
Hello, !  
World
```

Upon investigation, Powershell seems to be ignoring `$Name` in `"Hello, $Name!"` completely, as running

```
HelloWorld("Hello, !", "World")
```

Produces output identical to above. Additionally, it doesn't seem to regard `"World"` as the value of `$Name`, since running

```
function HelloWorld
{  
    Param ($Greeting, $Name)
    $Name
}
HelloWorld("Hello, $Name!", "World")
```

Produces no output.

Is there a way to get the expanding string to work when passed in as a function parameter?

Comment: First, variable substitution happens when you construct the string, not when you display it. Second, you are not calling `HelloWorld` properly: you are passing array with two strings as `$Greeting` and nothing to `$Name`.

Comment: @PetSerAl Thanks, I see what you mean - I should be calling `HelloWorld "Hello, $Name!" "World"` to assign the variables correctly. That of course still produces `Hello, !`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue occurs because the `$Name` string replacement is happening outside of the function, before the `$Name` variable is populated inside of the function.

You could do something like this instead:

```
function HelloWorld
{  
    Param ($Greeting, $Name)
    $Greeting -replace '\$Name',$Name
}

HelloWorld -Greeting 'Hello, $Name!' -Name 'World'
```

By using single quotes, we send the literal greeting of `Hello, $Name` in and then do the replacement of this string inside the function using `-Replace` (we have to put a `\` before the `$` in the string we're replace because `$` is a regex special character).

Answer (score 6):

In order to ***delay* string interpolation and perform it on demand, with *then-current* values**, you must **use `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()`<sup>[1]</sup> on a *single-quoted* string that acts as a *template***:

```
function HelloWorld
{  
    Param ($Greeting, $Name)
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($Greeting)
}

HelloWorld 'Hello, $Name!' 'World'   # -> 'Hello, World!'
```

Note how `'Hello, $Name!'` is *single*-quoted to prevent instant expansion (interpolation).

Also note how `HelloWorld` is called with its arguments separated with *spaces*, not `,`, and without `(...)`.

<sup>**In PowerShell, functions are invoked like command-line executables** - `foo arg1 arg2` - not like C# *methods* - `foo(arg1, arg2)` - see [`Get-Help about_Parsing`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing).

If you accidentally use `,` to separate your arguments, you'll construct an *array* that a function sees as a *single* argument.

To help you avoid accidental use of method syntax, you can use [`Set-StrictMode -Version 2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/set-strictmode) or higher, but note that that entails additional strictness checks.</sup>

Note that since PowerShell functions by default also see variables defined in the parent scope (all ancestral scopes), you could simply define any variables that the template references in the calling scope instead of declaring individual parameters such as `$Name`:

```
function HelloWorld
{  
    Param ($Greeting) # Pass the template only.
    $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($Greeting)
}

$Name = 'World'  # Define the variable(s) used in the template.
HelloWorld 'Hello, $Name!'     # -> 'Hello, World!'
```

**Caveat**:

- PowerShell string interpolation supports embedding *arbitrary commands*, via `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--), e.g., `"Today is $(Get-Date)"` - so **unless you fully control or trust the template string**, this technique can be **security risk.** For **a solution that *suppresses* command expansion, i.e. allows *variable* references only**, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77222536/45375).

---

[Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1630171/ansgar-wiechers) proposes a ***safe alternative* based on [.NET string formatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=netframework-4.7.2#Starting) via PowerShell's `-f` operator** and **indexed placeholders** (`{0}`, `{1}`, ...):

Note that you can then no longer apply *transformations* on the arguments as part of the template string or embed commands in it in general.

```
function HelloWorld
{  
    Param ($Greeting, $Name)
    $Greeting -f $Name
}

HelloWorld 'Hello, {0}!' 'World'     # -> 'Hello, World!'
```

Pitfalls:

- PowerShell's string expansion uses the *invariant* culture, whereas the `-f` operator performs *culture-sensitive* formatting (snippet requires PSv3+):

  ```
    $prev = [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture
    # Temporarily switch to culture with "," as the decimal mark
    [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = 'fr-FR' 

    # string expansion: culture-invariant: decimal mark is always "."
    $v=1.2; "$v";  # -> '1.2'

    # -f operator: culture-sensitive: decimal mark is now ","
    '{0}' -f $v    # -> '1,2'  

    [cultureinfo]::CurrentCulture = $prev
  ```
- PowerShell's string expansion supports expanding *collections* (arrays) - it expands them to a space-separated list - whereas the `-f` operator only supports *scalars* (single values):

  ```
    $arr = 'one', 'two'

    # string expansion: array is converted to space-separated list
    "$var" # -> 'one two'

    # -f operator: array elements are syntactically treated as separate values
    # so only the *first* element replaces {0}
    '{0}' -f $var  # -> 'one'
    # If you use a *nested* array to force treatment as a single array-argument,
    # you get a meaningless representation (.ToString() called on the array)
    '{0}' -f (, $var)  # -> 'System.Object[]'
  ```

---

<sup>[1] Surfacing the functionality of the `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` *method* in a more discoverable way, namely via an `Expand-String` *cmdlet*, is the subject of [GitHub feature-request issue #11693](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11693).</sup>