# Import from strings from a text file and only expand variables

Tags: powershell

I am reading a text file. I need to expand the variable in the string.  I do not want to run the whole line.  It is like I am getting a '' Literal string.  I do not what kind of string has "".

1. make the a text file called C:\temp\testfile.txt.
2. add the line `Thisbrokenit test1 $OnlyExpandThisValue`
3. run the code

   > $OnlyExpandThisValue = "It WORKS!"
   >
   > $testit = Get-Content C:\temp\testfile.txt
   >
   > Invoke-Expression $testit
   >
   > $($testit)

I am needing to get the result below.

Thisbrokeit test1 It WORKS!

Comment: In short: Use `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($string)` to perform string interpolation on demand - but be sure you either fully control or trust the input; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556308/45375) to the linked duplicate.