# Referencing an object's properties inside a string inside a foreach statement

Tags: powershell

Apologies in advance! Self taught (read: just started with no coding experience), so I may have some incorrect terminology.

I have a function that loads registry user hives and produces a global variable $global:userprofiles with userprofile SIDs. This part works fine and looks like this:

```
SID                                          
---                                          
S-1-5-21-3411627100-1852253463-1168398051-500
S-1-5-21-3711182449-2936729792-314897268-1001
DEFAULTUSER
```

After that function I need to manipulate a registry key. If I do the following ....

```
$key = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($userprofile.SID)\Something\someone"
foreach($userprofile in $global:userprofiles)
{echo $key}
```

I get the following output:

```
Registry::HKEY_USERS\DEFAULTUSER\Something\someone
Registry::HKEY_USERS\DEFAULTUSER\Something\someone
Registry::HKEY_USERS\DEFAULTUSER\Something\someone
```

Not great.

If I put $key inside the foreach like this:

```
foreach($userprofile in $global:userprofiles)
{
  $key = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($userprofile.SID)\Something\someone"
  echo $key
}
```

It works:

```
Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3411627100-1852253463-1168398051-500\Something\for\someone
Registry::HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-3711182449-2936729792-314897268-1001\Something\for\someone
Registry::HKEY_USERS\DEFAULTUSER\Something\for\someone
```

It took me entirely too long to figure that out and I can't seem to understand where I went wrong. Can someone provide an ELI5 so I don't goof something similar in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `"Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($userprofile.SID)\Something\someone"`

is an instance of an [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings), which means that expansion (interpolation) happens *instantly*.

That is, the value of `$userprofile.SID` *at that time* is substituted for the `$($userprofile.SID)` [subexpression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) and a *static string value* is returned.

You mistakenly expected your string to act like a string *template*, to be (re-)interpolated *every time it is accessed*, based on *then*-current values.

- This functionality requires a different approach: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556308/45375).

Placing your expandable string inside a `foreach` loop:

> ```
>  foreach($userprofile in $global:userprofiles)  
>   {
>     $key = "Registry::HKEY_USERS\$($userprofile.SID)\Something\someone"  
>     echo $key  
>   }
> ```

solved your problem, because a *new* expandable string is then created *in each iteration*, where interpolation is based on the then-current values in each iteration.