# PowerShell: Use undeclared variable in string

Tags: string, powershell, variables

I'm trying to figure out how I can use undeclared variables in a string. This is a simplified example to demonstrate my issue

```
[string]$sentence="My dog is $age years old"
[int]$age = 6 
$sentence | write-output

$age = 3
$sentence | write-output
```

Looking for this output:

```
   My dog is 6 years old

   My dog is 3 years old
```

Getting this output:

```
   My dog is  years old

   My dog is  years old
```

I've tried the following:

```
  "My dog is `$age years old" #My dog is $age years old
  $("My dog is `$age years old") #My dog is $age years old
  $("My dog is $age years old") #My dog is 3 years old
```

Is it possible in any way to make this more compact? or is this the only way?

---

edit: I noticed the focus is on strings. I will share my code where this was an issue. I need to migrate a bunch of  VBS-scripts (>40) varying from 20 lines to 2000 lines to Powershell

**VBS-file:**

```vb
    Function InitializeApp

        Dim sPath
        
        ...

    End function
```

**Powershell Script:**

```
$vbs=Get-Content -path $path #get content in array, one line per index
$rules=
@(
    [pscustomobject]@{
        "name"="func_start";
        "vbs" = 'Function (?<V1>\w*)'; # The regex named group V1 will initialized when match is found
        "ps" = {"Function $1() `{`n"} # Group V1 is to be inserted in replacement string
    }
)

function Invoke-TestAndReplace($line,$ruleName){
    $r_vbs=$($rules.where({$_.name -eq $ruleName}).vbs) # Function (?<V1>\w*)
    $r_ps=$($rules.where({$_.name -eq $ruleName}).ps) # {"Function $1() `{`n"}
    if( $regex = ($line | select-string -pattern $r_vbs )) {
        $0=$regex[0].Matches.Groups.Where({$_.name -eq "0"}).value # Function InitializeApp
        $1=$regex[0].Matches.Groups.Where({$_.name -eq "V1"}).value # InitializeApp
        $2=$regex[0].Matches.Groups.Where({$_.name -eq "V2"}).value #
        $r_ps = & $r_ps # Function InitializeApp() {
        $replace = $line.replace($0,$r_ps) # Function InitializeApp -> Function InitializeApp() {
    } else {$replace = $line} #keep old value
    return $replace
}
$newVBS=@()
foreach($line in $vbs){
    $line = Invoke-TestAndReplace -line $line -rulename "func_start"
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using expanding strings as Powershell function parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51555635/using-expanding-strings-as-powershell-function-parameters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer shows an overcomplicated alternative to the [nice answer from Joel Coehoorn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71984524/15339544). You can use a [Script Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks?view=powershell-7.2), to store an expression (including your `$age` variable) and then execute it.

```sh
$sentence = { "My dog is $age years old" }
$age = 6 
& $sentence | write-output # => My dog is 6 years old

$age = 3
& $sentence | write-output # => My dog is 3 years old
```

If you want your script block to "remember" the value of a variable at the moment it was created you can use it's [`.GetNewClosure()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.scriptblock.getnewclosure?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0), for example:

```
$expressions = foreach($i in 0..5) {
    { "Value of `$i was $i in this iteration" }.GetNewClosure()
}
$expressions.foreach{ & $_ }
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what  I was looking for! In my case this was needed for some complex regex stuff.

Comment: You can just put `| write-output` at the end of your $sentence script block instead of writing it everytime. But also strings naturally just write-output so it seems overkill to me.

Comment: @RobertCotterman just using that because OP was using it in his question, and I know.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know how to do this with interpolation, but I can do it with the older .Net `String.Format()` method like this:

```
$sentence = "My dog is {0} years old."

$age = 6
[string]::Format($sentence, $age) | Write-Output
# => My dog is 6 years old

$age = 3
[string]::Format($sentence, $age) | Write-Output
# => My dog is 3 years old

[string]::Format($sentence, 12)   | Write-Output
# => My dog is 12 years old
```

Which we can shorten like this (thank you commenters):

```
$sentence = "My dog is {0} years old."

$age = 6
Write-Output ($sentence -f $age)
# => My dog is 6 years old

$age = 3
Write-Output ($sentence -f $age)
# => My dog is 3 years old

Write-Output ($sentence -f 12)
# => My dog is 12 years old
```

Also note the different placeholder in the template string.

Comment: nicely done, not sure why I didn't think of this ‍♂️ uselessly overcomplicating it. in powershell the [`-f` format operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#format-operator--f) is the equivalent of `String.Format(..)` in case you want to add it to your answer

Comment: A good approach. You can make it more concise with `$s = "my dog is {0}"; Write-Host ($s -f 6)`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I did not know about `-f`, thanks for that. I'll definitely use it more now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ExpandString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-string-substitutions?view=powershell-7.2#executioncontext-expandstring)

```
$sentence = 'My dog is $age years old.'

$age = 4
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($sentence)
# My dog is 4 years old.

$age = 5
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($sentence)
# My dog is 5 years old.
```

You could also define a function and call the function

```
function sentence([int]$age) {
    "My dog is $age years old"
}

1..5 | ForEach-Object { sentence -age $_ }

# My dog is 1 years old
# My dog is 2 years old
# My dog is 3 years old
# My dog is 4 years old
# My dog is 5 years old
```