# Checking existence of several user's network "Profile Folder" from list of usernames

Tags: powershell, foreach, directory, exists

Trying to reach out to one server (by name) and search for the Profile DIR for each username's existence from the list of users, whom I need to delete. After many many attempts, still seeing a result of "$User profile not found." Even though I can see that it is clearly in the DIR. When I run one specific test for one user, it shows up.. example:
`

```
    $DelUser = "user.name"
    $ProfileUser = "\\dc1\P$\Profiles\$DelUser" + ".V6"

    if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($ProfileUser)) {
    "......$DelUser..... EXISTS!"

    else {
    "$DelUser Path NOT FOUND!"
    }
    }
```

Pulling from the source (txt) file (I've also tried using a csv file with `import-csv` with same results) I try to go through the list and search for the existence of each user folder with the below code.
User folders are in the `user.name.V6` format.
Below a sample with some commented alternate attempts.

```
    $DelUser = Get-Content -Path C:\DelFolder\Delete-DC1-Users.txt
    $UserPath = "\\DC1\P$\Profiles\$User" + ".V6"

    foreach ($User in $DelUser) {
    if ([System.IO.Directory]::Exists($UserPath)) {
    Write-Host "$UserPath EXISTS"
    #if (Test-Path -Path $UserPath) {
    # if ($UserPath) {
    # Write-Host "$User Folder Exists" 
    }


    else {
    Write-Host "$User Folder DOES NOT EXIST" 
    }
    }
```

And at best I'll see the `$User Folder DOES NOT EXIST` even though it does in fact exist on the server.

I've also tried using `Test-Path` to no avail, as seen above in the commented out lines.

Thank you!
P.S. My first posted question here, so my apologies for any mishaps or mistakes!

Comment: Place your `$UserPath` variable inside your loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `$UserPath = "\\dc1\P$\Profiles\$User" + ".V6"`

Your use of `"..."`, i.e. of an [*expandable* (interpolating) string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) , means that the reference to variable `$User` is *instantly* expanded, resulting in storing a *static* string in variable `$UserPath`; that is, you're "baking in" the value of `$DelUser` *at that time* (and since `$User` isn't defined until *later*, the expansion will will result in the *empty string* by default).

What you need instead is to **move your `$UserPath = ...` assignment *inside your `foreach` loop* so that the `"..."` is string is *re-evaluated in each iteration*, based on the then-current value of `$User`**:

```bash
$delUser = Get-Content -LiteralPath C:\DelFolder\Delete-DC1-Users.txt

foreach ($user in $delUser) {
  # Determine the path *for the $user at hand*.
  $userPath = "\\DC1\P$\Profiles\$user.V6"
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $userPath) {
    "$userPath EXISTS"
  }
  else {
    "$user Folder DOES NOT EXIST" 
  }
}
```

Note:

- The `".V6"` suffix was folded directly into the `"..."` string - no need for appending it separately with [`+`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arithmetic_Operators).

  - Note that such a suffix is *not* treated as an attempt to access a *property* of the `$user` variable - for the latter, you'd need enclosure in [`$(...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's string-interpolation rules.
- It is safer to use `-LiteralPath` rather than `-Path` when you know you're dealing with literal (verbatim) paths rather than [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards).
- You could add `-Type Container` to the [`Test-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path) call to limit the test to whether a *directory* (rather than a *file*) with the given path exists, though that's probably not necessary here.
- The [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) calls were omitted in favor of *implicit* output of the strings (implied [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output)), though note that the former prints directly to the *display*,<sup>[1]</sup> whereas the latter produces *data* output that can be captured.

  - See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375) for more information.
- While not enforced, a worthwhile *convention* to observe is to start the names of regular variables with *lowercase* letters (e.g, `$user`) and to only start *parameter* variables with an uppercase letter (e.g. `$Path` inside a `param(...)` block).

---

Note that **there *are* ways to perform string *templating***, where string expansion (interpolation) is performed *on demand* on a technically verbatim string, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556308/45375).

However, in the case at hand the solution above is simpler.

---

<sup>[1] In PSv5+ `Write-Host` writes to the [information stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection), whose output *can* be captured, but only via `6>`.</sup>

Comment: BEAUTIFUL!! Muchas Gracias @mklement0 !! That did the trick!!!

Comment: Excellent notes! I've got some homework to do! I can't say thank you enough!!