# How to use variable value from a function that calls another function where variable already defined?

Tags: powershell, function, variables, scope

```
$logDate = Get-Date
$codeBlockId = "NOTHING"
$addToCodeRunLog = Write-Host "However, inside addToCodeRunLog, codeBlockId is $codeBlockId. This line comes second"

function addCodeBlockLogs {
Write-Host "inside CodeBlockLogs, the value of codeBlockID is $codeBlockId. This line comes first."
$addToCodeRunLog
}

function deviceInfoLog {
$codeBlockId = "1002"
addCodeBlockLogs
}

deviceInfoLog
```

Returns:

```
However, inside addToCodeRunLog, codeBlockId is NOTHING. This line comes second
inside CodeBlockLogs, the value of codeBlockID is 1002. This line comes first.
```

1. Why does the value of `$codeBlockID` not get changed when `$addCodeToRunLog` is called from the function?
2. Why does is return the value of `$addCodeToRunLog` before returning the `Write-Host` value of the previous line?

Answer (score 2):

> 2. Why does is return the value of $addCodeToRunLog before returning the Write-Host value of the previous line?

Because **you're mistakenly using [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) in your assignment**:

```bash
# Write-Host prints *to the display*, it doesn't output to the *pipeline*.
# Therefore:
#  * The message *prints instantly*
#  * *Nothing* is stored in var. $addToCodeRunLog, because Write-Host
#    produced *no success-output stream (pipeline) output*.
$addToCodeRunLog = Write-Host "However, inside addToCodeRunLog, codeBlockId is $codeBlockId. This line comes second"
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60534138/45375) for background information.

To instead store the string in your `$addToCodeRunLog` variable, either replace [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) with [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) or, preferably, just assign the string directly:

```bash
$addToCodeRunLog = "However, inside addToCodeRunLog, codeBlockId is $codeBlockId. This line comes second"
```

However, this will still not do what you want, as discussed next.

---

> 1. Why does the value of $codeBlockID not get changed when $addCodeToRunLog is called from the function?

Even if you fix your assignment as shown above, it **uses the value of variable `$codeBlockId` at the point *when the assignment statement containing the `"..."` string is executed*, and "bakes it into" the string** - that is how [expandable (double-quoted) string (`"..."`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) work in PowerShell.

If you want to ***defer* expansion (string interpolation)** for *on-demand interpolation* based on the *then-current variable value(s)*, you need to :

- Either: Use ***string templating***, where you define your string as a
  [verbatim (single-quoted) string (`'...'`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#single-quoted-strings) and later call `$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString()` with it - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51556308/45375) (also shows an alternative with `-f`).
- Or: You can **wrap your expandable string in a *function*** - as shown in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75772561/45375) - which implicitly also defers expansion.

  - PowerShell's *dynamic scoping* ensures that the child scope in which your wrapper function executes sees the desired `$codeBlockId` value from its parent scope - see the conceptual [about_Scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Scopes) help topic.
  - Note: A **variant solution** based on the same principles would be to define your variable as a **[*script block* (`{ ... }`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)**, which you can invoke on demand with `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-), in order to perform on-demand expansion:

    ```bash
    $addToCodeRunLog = { "`$foo = $foo" }
    $foo = 1
    & $addToCodeRunLog # -> '$foo = 1'
    $foo = 2
    & $addToCodeRunLog # -> '$foo = 2'
    ```

Comment: Thanks. I actually modified the code to include Write-Host as a way to simplify it for SO, but I suspect the same rules apply to the original. Thank you for your comprehensive answer. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because `$addCodeToRunLog` is declared as a variable rather than a function. I fixed it by changing it to:

```
$logDate = Get-Date
$codeBlockId = "NOTHING"
function addToCodeRunLog {
 Write-Host "However, inside addToCodeRunLog, codeBlockId is $codeBlockId. This line comes second"
}

function addCodeBlockLogs {
Write-Host "inside CodeBlockLogs, the value of codeBlockID is $codeBlockId. This line comes first."
addToCodeRunLog
}

function deviceInfoLog {
$codeBlockId = "1002"
addCodeBlockLogs
}

deviceInfoLog
```

Comment: I've restructured my answer to directly address your two questions. Using a function indeed avoids the problem, because it _defers_ evaluation of the expandable string (`"..."`) until the function is called, using the then-current variable value. The answer to the second question is that you mistakenly used `Write-Host` in your variable assignment, which prints immediately to the display and stores nothing in the variable.